# How to delete to blackhole register in VScode's Vim mode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I really want to use Visual Code and it looks like it has a great Vim mode. Unfortunately I'm one of those people that changed my `.vimrc` so that deletes, changes and the like would move to the blackhole register so that it wouldn't take over my last yank.

Does anyone know of a way to do something similar for `dd` or `C` mappings? I've tried it various ways but can't seem to get it to work.

It seems to only work with a leader like so

```
"vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
    {
        "before": ["<leader>","d"],
        "after": ["\"", "_", "d", "d"]
    },
],
"vim.leader": "<space>",
```

Doing the following though doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
"vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
    {
        "before": ["d","d"],
        "after": ["\"", "_", "d", "d"]
    },
],
```

Answer (score 5):

Black hole register mapping functionality has been fixed [in the recent PR](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/pull/3081), just a few months after you posted this question. Update your VScode to the latest stable release and your mappings should work fine.

---

If you are interested in how to disable **cut** functionality for `d` command, here is how to do it. Put this in your *settings.json*:

```
"vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
    {
        "before": ["d"],
        "after": [ "\"", "_", "d" ]
    }
]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: can you describe what this is doing? What does \\_d translate to and how is it different from d?

Comment: @55Cancri it's "_d, the \" is to put the "